# Angularjs accessing scope for dynamic elements

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, scope, angular-ng-if

I have 2 radio input fields

```
<input type="radio" name="location_type" ng-model="location_type" value="ANYWHERE" required> Anywhere
<input type="radio" name="location_type" ng-model="location_type" value="FIXED" required> Fixed
```

If the selected radio is value is "FIXED", another text field is displayed using ng-if. This text field have 'required' validation.

```
<div ng-if="location_type == 'FIXED'">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" ng-model="city" placeholder="Enter City" ng-blur="cname=''" ng-focus="cname='bold'" required>
</div
```

I do not get the value of `$scope.city` in controller because the input `city` is displayed dynamically when I click on the radio button with value value `FIXED`.

If I use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, I get the `$scope.city` variable value in controller, but in that case the validation for city input is working even when I select radio button `ANYWHERE`. The city field will be hidden and its validation need not work when I select radio button `ANYWHERE`.

Who can make my day :)

Comment: Just try use `ng-required="location_type=='FIXED'"` on **input**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive `create new child scope`.

As per your your html, you are assigning `city` to this `child scope` and not the parent scope which is your controller.

So,not accessible in controller.

So, you need to do something like this.

Declare object in parent controller like this ;

```
$scope.parentObj = {};
```

And change your html ;

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" ng-model="parentObj" required>
```

Now, your child scope will get the inherited object property from controller;

So, it will reflect in controller.

Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iGDgafXLamrsuTfc5OJ4?p=preview)

Comment: Need not initialize element inside parentobj. $scope.parentObj={} works

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: ok, can you remove the city parameter as empty from parentObj initialize, as its actually not required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng-required="boolValueOrExpression"` ? It's a conditionally validation in your case.